# Google Sheets formula IF or SUM with conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm looking for some much needed help after hours of looking.

I have lets call it a task list of things to do. Columns A B and C have text, column D is a number (hours it will take me to complete task) and column E is empty and use it to 'tick' off my list by typing 'x' with conditional formatting this in turn 'greys out' the whole row - and it also removes the number on this row from my chart, which is exactly what I want, but I also want my total values of column D to reflect this. I put my SUM in column F.

I want to SUM (or add together all values in column D) which is fine with a simple SUM formula, but I want sheets to minus any number that I have completed with my 'x' in column E. I'm sure it must be possible as it does this automatically with any chart I add, but just want 1 cell with the answer?

FYI the conditional formatting I use is =$E10="x" making the row grey if there's an 'x' there and I also use `=ISBLANK(#REF!)` if no 'x' is present.

Comment: OK so I have figured out how to do the exact opposite of what I'm after using the formula =SUMIF(E11:E20,"x",D11:D20) this adds all the values in column D together but only if Column E has an 'x' input, I want it to Add all values in column D that dont have an x in column E

Answer (score -1):

OK
Thanks for stopping by, I finally did it with =SUMIF(E11:E20,"<>x",D11:D20) where <> is not equal too.